# How to navigate to new screen in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new to Flutter and the project I am working on is developed by another developer.

I want to navigate to One Screen from Login screen.
But I am getting an error

> The following assertion was thrown building WillPopScope(dependencies:
> [_ModalScopeStatus], state: _WillPopScopeState#50ddb):
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 3566 pos 18: '!keyReservation.contains(key)': is not true.
> WillPopScope
>
> WillPopScope:file:///Users/admin/Desktop/Flutter%20workspace/MyApp/lib/src/core/util/navigation/router.dart:489:12
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #2      NavigatorState._debugCheckDuplicatedPageKeys. (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3566:18)
> #3      NavigatorState._debugCheckDuplicatedPageKeys (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3571:6)
> #4      NavigatorState._updatePages. (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3630:7)
> #5      NavigatorState._updatePages (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3633:6)
> #6      NavigatorState.didUpdateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3552:7)
> #7      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5260:55)

I don't understand the error is for framework or for architecture designed.

The code for router is as below

```
enum NavigationType { add, replaceCurrent, replaceAll, removeUntil }

///[RouteManger] is the helper class used by the [MaterialApp] widget
class RouteManger extends RouterDelegate<List<RouteSettings>>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<List<RouteSettings>> {
  RouteManger._private();

  static final _instance = RouteManger._private();

  static RouteManger get instance => _instance;

  ///[_pages] maintains the stack of routes in the navigation
  static final List<Page> _pages = <Page>[];

  ///[_defaultInitialPage] is the page that is loaded first when the app launches
  static const String _defaultInitialPage = Pages.pinAuthView;

  static BuildContext? get currentContext =>
      _instance.navigatorKey.currentContext;

  static void init() {
    try {
      _instance.navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
      if (_pages.isEmpty) {
        _pages.add(_instance
            ._createPage(const RouteSettings(name: _defaultInitialPage)));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  ///[navigatorKey] is the global key used for by router for navigation
  @override
  late final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  // @override
  // GlobalKey<NavigatorState> get key => navigatorKey;

  ///[currentRoute] returns null if there is no current route, or it is anonymous
  static String? get currentRoute =>
      /*_pages.isNotEmpty ? _pages.last.name : null;*/ _pages.isNotEmpty
          ? _pages.last.name
          : '/';

  /// When no user is logged-in, calling [_loginSessionAwareRedirection] redirects the user to the [noSessionPage]
  /// And redirects to [page] when user is logged in
  /// Default value of [noSessionPage] is set to [LoginView]
  static Widget _loginSessionAwareRedirection(Widget page,
      {Widget noSessionPage = const LoginView()}) {
    /// Checking if the user is logged-in before redirecting to [page]
    if (AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.isLoggedIn) {
      return page;
    }

    /// When no user is logged-in, redirecting to [noSessionPage] page instead
    else {
      return noSessionPage;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> popRoute() async {
    if (_pages.length > 1) {
      _pages.removeLast();
      notifyListeners();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(List<RouteSettings> configuration) async {}

  bool _onPopPage(Route route, dynamic result) {
    if (!route.didPop(result)) return false;
    popRoute();
    return true;
  }

  static void navigateTo(String name,
      {String removeUntilRoute = Pages.root,
      dynamic arguments,
      final NavigationType navigationType = NavigationType.add}) {
    switch (navigationType) {
      case NavigationType.add:
        _pages.add(instance
            ._createPage(RouteSettings(name: name, arguments: arguments)));
        break;

      case NavigationType.replaceCurrent:
        if (_pages.isNotEmpty) {
          _pages.removeLast();
        }
        _pages.add(instance
            ._createPage(RouteSettings(name: name, arguments: arguments)));
        break;

      case NavigationType.replaceAll:
        if (_pages.isNotEmpty) {
          _pages.clear();
        }
        _pages.add(instance
            ._createPage(RouteSettings(name: name, arguments: arguments)));
        break;

      case NavigationType.removeUntil:
        while (_pages.isNotEmpty &&
            _pages.last.name != null &&
            _pages.last.name!.compareTo(removeUntilRoute) != 0) {
          _pages.removeLast();
        }
        _pages.add(instance
            ._createPage(RouteSettings(name: name, arguments: arguments)));
        break;
    }

    try {
      instance.notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      log('Error calling notifyListeners: $e');
    }
  }

  static void navigateBack({
    bool useContextBasedPop = false,
    BuildContext? context,
    bool rootNavigator = false,
  }) {
    if (useContextBasedPop && context != null) {
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: rootNavigator).pop();
    } else {
      _instance.popRoute();
    }
  }

  static void navigateBackTo(String name) {
    while (_pages.length > 1 &&
        _pages.last.name != null &&
        _pages.last.name!.compareTo(name) != 0) {
      _pages.removeLast();
    }
    _instance.notifyListeners();
  }

  MaterialPage _createPage(RouteSettings settings) {
    late final Widget child;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case Pages.root:
      case Pages.home:
      case Pages.login:
        HomeViewPages? tab;
        if (settings.arguments is HomeViewPages) {
          tab = settings.arguments as HomeViewPages;
          log('Selected tab $tab');
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(
            HomeView(page: tab ?? HomeViewPages.home));
        break;

      case Pages.register:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(HomeView(),
            noSessionPage: const RegistrationView());
        break;

      case Pages.setLoginPinView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(SetPinAuthView());
        break;

      case Pages.pinAuthView:
        /*child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(LocalAuthController
                .isDeviceSupported
            ? PinAuthView(PinAuthViewParams(
                name: AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.user != null
                    ? AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.user.fullName
                    : '',
                username: AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.user != null
                    ? AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.user.mobile
                    : '',
                biometricAuthSupported:
                    LocalAuthController.isBiometricSupported,
                biometricAuthMode: LocalAuthController.biometricAuthMode))
            : AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.isLoginPinSet
                ? PinAuthView(PinAuthViewParams(
                    name: AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.user.fullName.trim(),
                    username: AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.user.mobile,
                    biometricAuthSupported:
                        LocalAuthController.isBiometricSupported,
                    biometricAuthMode: LocalAuthController.biometricAuthMode))
                : SetPinAuthView());*/

        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(
            AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.isLoginPinSet
                // LocalAuthController.isDeviceSupported
                ? PinAuthView(PinAuthViewParams(
                    name: AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.user.fullName.trim(),
                    username: AuthDatasourceLocal.instance.user.mobile,
                    biometricAuthSupported:
                        LocalAuthController.isBiometricSupported,
                    biometricAuthMode: LocalAuthController.biometricAuthMode))
                : SetPinAuthView());
        break;

      case Pages.brokerLoginOptionsView:
        if (settings.arguments is! BrokerLoginOptionsViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(BrokerLoginOptionsView(
            settings.arguments as BrokerLoginOptionsViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.brokerWebview:
        if (settings.arguments is! BrokerWebviewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(
            BrokerWebview(settings.arguments as BrokerWebviewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.digioESignView:
        if (settings.arguments is! DigioESignWebviewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(
            DigioESignWebview(settings.arguments as DigioESignWebviewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.alphaGenieView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const AlphaGenieView());
        break;

      case Pages.alphaMatterView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(
            AlphaMatterView(settings.arguments as AlphaMatterViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.alphaMindView:
        bool isInternational = false;
        if (settings.arguments is bool) {
          isInternational = settings.arguments as bool;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(
            AlphaMindView(isInternational: isInternational));
        break;

      case Pages.smartStockDetailsView:
        if (settings.arguments is! SmartStockDetailsViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(SmartStockDetailsView(
            settings.arguments as SmartStockDetailsViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.basketDetailsView:
        if (settings.arguments is! BasketDetailsViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(
            BasketDetailsView(settings.arguments as BasketDetailsViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.alphaMindBasketDetailsView:
        if (settings.arguments is! AlphaMindBasketDetailsViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(AlphaMindBasketDetailsView(
            settings.arguments as AlphaMindBasketDetailsViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.alphaMindInvestmentView:
        if (settings.arguments is! AlphaMindBasketInvestmentViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(AlphaMindBasketInvestmentView(
            settings.arguments as AlphaMindBasketInvestmentViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.transactionResultView:
        if (settings.arguments is! TransactionResultViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(TransactionResultView(
            settings.arguments as TransactionResultViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.watchListView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const WatchListView());
        break;

      case Pages.stockPurchasedSuccessfullyView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(TransactionResultView(
            settings.arguments as TransactionResultViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.supportPage:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const SupportPageView());
        break;

      case Pages.subscriptionPlansView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(SubscriptionPlansView());
        break;

      case Pages.editProfilePage:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const EditProfile());
        break;

      case Pages.stockCalculationPage:
        if (settings.arguments is! StockCalculationViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(StockCalculationView(
            settings.arguments as StockCalculationViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.reviewYourOrderPage:
        if (settings.arguments is! ReviewYourOrderPageParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(ReviewYourOrderPage(
            settings.arguments as ReviewYourOrderPageParams));
        break;

      case Pages.brokerLoginReviewYourOrderPage:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(
            const BrokerLoginReviewYourOrderPage());
        break;

      case Pages.forgotPinView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const ForgotPinView());
        break;

      case Pages.singleStockSellConfirmationView:
        if (settings.arguments is! SingleStockSellConfirmationViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(SingleStockSellConfirmationView(
            settings.arguments as SingleStockSellConfirmationViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.transactionHistoryPage:
        // child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const TransactionHistoryPage());
        child = const TransactionHistoryPage();
        break;

      case Pages.portfolioBasketDetailsView:
        if (settings.arguments is! PortfolioBasketViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(PortfolioBasketView(
            settings.arguments as PortfolioBasketViewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.paymentStatusView:
        if (settings.arguments is! PaymentResultViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child =
            PaymentResultView(settings.arguments as PaymentResultViewParams);
        break;

      /*case Pages.agreementView:
        if (settings.arguments is! AgreementViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = AgreementView(settings.arguments as AgreementViewParams);
        break;*/

      case Pages.kycStatusView:
        try {
          if (settings.arguments is! KYCViewParams) {
            child = _errorRoute;
          }
          child = KYCView(settings.arguments as KYCViewParams);
        } catch (e) {
          log(e.toString());
        }
        break;

      case Pages.riskProfileView:
        if (settings.arguments is! RiskProfileViewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = RiskProfileView(settings.arguments as RiskProfileViewParams);
        break;

      case Pages.verifyEmailPage:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const VerifyEmailView());
        break;

      case Pages.poorNetworkConnectionView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const PoorNetworkConnection());
        break;

      case Pages.underMaintenanceView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const UnderMaintenanceView());
        break;

      /* case Pages.declaimerView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(DeclaimerView());
        break;*/

      case Pages.notificationListView:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const NavigationViewWidget());
        break;

      case Pages.readPDFWebView:
        if (settings.arguments is! ReadPdfWebviewParams) {
          child = _errorRoute;
        }
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(
            ReadPdfWebview(settings.arguments as ReadPdfWebviewParams));
        break;

      case Pages.aboutUs:
        child = _loginSessionAwareRedirection(const AboutUsView());
        break;

      default:
        child = _errorRoute;
        break;
    }

    return MaterialPage(
        child: child,
        key: ValueKey(settings.name),
        name: settings.name,
        arguments: settings.arguments);
  }

  static Widget get _errorRoute {
    return const ErrorView(
      title: 'Navigation Error',
      message: '404',
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        switch (currentRoute) {
          // case Pages.root:
          // case Pages.home:
          // case Pages.login:
          case Pages.register:
            
            // case Pages.pinAuthView:
            // case Pages.setLoginPinView:
            showGenericActionDialog(
                context: context,
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                actions: [
                  GenericActionDialogItem(
                      title: 'Yes',
                      closeDialogOnPress: true,
                      onPressed: () {
                        navigateBack();
                      }),
                  GenericActionDialogItem(
                      title: 'No', closeDialogOnPress: true, onPressed: () {})
                ]);
            return false;

          default:
            return true;
        }
      },
      /*onWillPop: () async{
        return true;
      },*/
      child: Navigator(
        key: navigatorKey,
        pages: List.of(_pages),
        onPopPage: _onPopPage,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RouteInformationParserManager
    extends RouteInformationParser<RouteInformation> {
  RouteInformationParserManager._private();

  static final _instance = RouteInformationParserManager._private();

  static RouteInformationParserManager get instance => _instance;

  @override
  Future<RouteInformation> parseRouteInformation(
      RouteInformation routeInformation) async {
    return routeInformation;
  }
}
```

The error thrown at line number 488 to the ***`return WillPopScope`*** method.

And the navigation happening like this

```
InkWell(
                                 onTap: (){
                                 // RouteManger.navigateTo(Pages.register);
                                  RouteManger.navigateTo(
                                       Pages.brokerLoginOptionsView,
                                       arguments: BrokerLoginOptionsViewParams(
                                       onLoggedIn:
                                      controller.onBrokerProfileUpdated,
                                       onLoggedOut: controller
                                       .onBrokerProfileUpdated));
                                 },
                                 child: Image.asset(
                                   Assets.callIcon,
                                   width: 50,
                                   height: 50,
                                 ),
                               ),
```

If I navigate to the register page then it is redirected, but for other than register for all the pages I am getting same error.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.